# Django - make a form remember its checkbox values

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, checkbox

I'll address this question using a base setup:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    required_field = models.CharField("some label", max_length=10)
    another_required_field = models.CharField("some label", max_length=10)
    checkbox = models.BooleanField("some label")

# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

# views.py
class MyView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    template_name = 'some-template.html'
```

Now suppose I check the checkbox and fill just one of the required fields. The form obviously doesn't pass validation and gets back with errors and all. Problem is, the value of the checkbox comes back unchecked. This is not a big deal with just one BooleanField, but I'm working on a project where I have tons of checkboxes. Check them all from scratch is rather frustrating. 
So I had a check on django's documentation and stumbled upon this paragraph regarding BooleanFields:

```
Since all Field subclasses have required=True by default, the validation condition here    
is important. If you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either True or 
False (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in 
required=False when creating the BooleanField.
```

And I did this:

```
# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if isinstance(field, forms.CheckboxInput):
                self.fields[field].required = False
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

but it didn't work. Again, checkboxes lose their state after the form didn't pass validation, so I guess that was not what I was looking for.

So my question is, is there a way to achieve that? I'm pretty sure there should be one, it would be great if some of you could at least drive me in the right direction. Thanks :-)

**EDIT**
After a bit of debugging, I solved the issue. Turns out I was using a custom template for crispy forms checkboxes, and I found a little bug in there.

Comment: you can post the view ?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think it would help at all. It's just a basic FormView subclass with nothing fancy. Anyway, I added it just for further info.

Comment: the problem is the view i post a example blow

Comment: How are you displaying the fields in your template?

Comment: I use django crispy forms for rendering, it should be okay on that end. I basically let the form print itself without any fancy customization. I'm still investigating on the causes, but now I don't really think it's something Django-related.

Comment: Well, seems like you hit the right spot. When you asked about how I was displaying the fields, I remembered I used a custom template for checkboxes instead of the crispy forms one, and there was a little error. Now it works as a charm. Thanks for the hint, Daniel Roseman :D

Answer (score 0):

Your view would need to populate the form from the `request.POST` dictionary as such:

```
def your_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # do whatever esle

    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'form': form})
```

Unless you pass the `request.POST` data, and/or an instance of the model you're editing, your form will be un-bound, and therefore not show any values that exist either in the POST data or from your model. If you're editing an instance, it would look like:

```
def your_view(request, id):
    my_model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=my_model_instance)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # do whatever esle

    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I'm using Class Based Views, so the form should be filled with request.POST data in the post method automatically. And by the way, the CharField is returned with the value I posted, it's just the checkbox that comes back unchecked. Maybe I should explain myself better. But thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the  problem is on your view:

view exemple:

```
def view(request):

if request.method == 'POST':#bound the form wit data from request.Post
    form = MyForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        #do somthing
        form.save()
    #if form not valid render the page.html with form that  has request.Post data 
    return render(request,'some-template.html',{'form': form})

else:
    form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'some-template.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: You can check the answer I posted to @Brandon, should apply to your reply too. Thanks anyway for the interest though.